# How many licenses of Microsoft Office 2010 do I need to buy?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, license

I have 10 computers in our church offices that I would like to upgrade to Microsoft Office 2010.

How many licenses do I need to buy?

Comment: You need at least 10

Answer (score 2):

Please check into Microsoft's special licensing for non-profit and charitable organizations which offers reduced cost volume licenses.  Certain specific groups even can get free software.  Start your search here.  http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/for-industries.aspx#tab=4

Comment: Be sure to do this!  Savings are significant for NFP and charities.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into Microsoft's Volume Licensing. You can contact Microsoft directly for a list of vendors;

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/how-to-buy/how-to-buy.aspx

With 10 license's you'll be looking at spending close to 3650.00$; this is a pretty great option and comes with 50 activation per licence, unlike the consumer versions.